# Windows Batch: write text to hosts

Tags: batch-file

I want write path to my Hosts file.
I use double quote to escape whitespace.
But my output will contain double quote.
Here is my code:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
CD C:\WINDOWS\System32\drivers\etc


@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion


set  arrayline[0]="119.81.166.227 test.google.com.tw"
set  arrayline[1]="119.81.166.227 test.yahoo.com.tw"


::read it using a FOR /L statement
for /l %%n in (0,1,1) do (
    (
    findstr /c:!arrayline[%%n]! hosts
    IF  ERRORLEVEL 0  echo !arrayline[%%n]! 


    )>> hosts

)
echo "complete"
pause
```

If I set variable like this

```
set  "arrayline[0]=119.81.166.227 test.google.com.tw"
```

Or remove quote

```
set  arrayline[1]=119.81.166.227 test.yahoo.com.tw
```

Also will get whitespace error
How to set text to my hosts file correct?

Comment: `set  "arrayline[0]=119.81.166.227 test.google.com.tw"` and then use quotes in the findstr expression

Comment: Wouldn't you want to write in the hosts file if the expression is NOT there?

Comment: yes, if no exist then insert text to file

Comment: Keep it simple.  You were way over thinking that. It even shows you in the FINDSTR help to use the quotes with the command. `FINDSTR /C:"hello there"`. Best practice is to never assign quotes to your string and use them when you need to preserve white space and special characters with your other commands.

Comment: Thanks for your suggest.I will study how to escape white space

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "hosts=C:\WINDOWS\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"


@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion


set  "arrayline[0]=119.81.166.227 test.google.com.tw"
set  "arrayline[1]=119.81.166.227 test.yahoo.com.tw"


::read it using a FOR /L statement
for /l %%n in (0,1,1) do (
    findstr /c:"!arrayline[%%n]!" "%hosts%" 1>nul 2>nul || (
      (echo(!arrayline[%%n]!)>>"%hosts%" 
    )
)
echo "complete"
pause
```

Comment: This works, but if there is an existing entry in the hosts file with no carriage return at the end, you may run into an issue.

Comment: I will echo a newline first.